# Docx file is hard to edit and show picture properties sometimes

Tags: microsoft-word

I have word file in .docx format.This file sometimes show picture properties. I need to edit this file and I cannot readjust text sometimes.

I have attached a screen shot. When I click a paragraph, file becomes an image.

Does anyone have a solution?

[image]